# ¿Como crear nueva activity en AndroidStudio 2.3.3?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Buenas, quisiera saber como crear una activity en AndroidStudio 2.3.3, hace alrededor de 1 año yo creaba activities con algo parecido a esto:

```
Intent i = new Intent(algo,algo);
i.startActivity();
```

Pero veo que actualmente el metodo startActivity(); no existe. Por favor diganme cual es la forma homologa de hacerlo actualmente, gracias.

Comment: Intent no contiene un método Activity!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se crea de la siguiente manera:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(DeAquiVengo.this,AquiVoy.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

El primer parametro de new Intent(), es el archivo en donde estas escribiendo el codigo y el segundo es hacia donde te estas llendo.

como recomendacion ponle la siguiente funcion al final para que te cierre dicho xml porque sino quedara detras.

```
finish();
```

Comment: Gracias, al parecer era yo quien no recordaba como era la utilización del método xD

Answer (score 2):

Si a lo que te refieres es abrir una `Activity` desde otra, sería así:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main2Activity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 1):

Si tratas de obtener el método de la clase `Intent`, no existe un método tal:

```
Intent i = new Intent(algo,algo);
i.startActivity(); //* incorrecto.
```

El método [startActivity()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#startActivity(android.content.Intent)) proviene del [contexto](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#startActivity(android.content.Intent)) (no de la clase `Intent`), por ejemplo si estas dentro de una Activity solo llama el método:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,  otraActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```